# Duplicate class when class contain number

Tags: css, vuejs2

I have an SPA application with VueJS (`2.0`). I've defined a class which name contain number

```css
.text-2xl {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Then I have a component:

```
  render(h) {
    return h('h1', {class: 'text-90 font-normal text-2xl'}, this.$slots.default)
  },
```

But when it render, the class `text-2xl` is duplicated:

[image]

Even it has other style `line-height: 2rem;` which I don't define in anywhere.
I also search in whole project, there only 1 place, which defined by me, has `text-2xl` class declared.

When I rename class to `text-xxl`, it work as normal.

I think it was a webpack config, this is my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  pages: {
    app: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'app.js'),
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html'
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This looks nothing related to css class configuration.

Can anyone explain this case?

Comment: Are u using tailwindcss?

Comment: yes, i'm using `tailwindcss@3.0.24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are using `tailwindcss`, the issue is that you actually have the class `text-2xl` duplicated (it is defined twice, once by you and once by `tailwindcss`.

Also, I am seeing that both have the same font-size so you might want to delete your custom-created class and leave only the `tailwindcss` one

Comment: Forgot to reply you answer, it's as you say. It may because i've updated `tailwindcss` version from `0.6` to `3.0.24`. Thanks